# SQL Server - Convert month number to date object

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm using the following code to return the month number of a result set

```
SELECT datepart(m,h.SessionDate ) AS sessionDate
```

Can i update this statement to return a timestamp (first of that month) instead of the month number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(Year(h.SessionDate), month(h.SessionDate), 1) AS sessionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or newer, you can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) as suggested by @HoneyBadger.

If you have an older version of SQL Server, use [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(h.SessionDate) + 1, h.SessionDate) AS DATE) AS sessionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate a date to the start of the month like so:

```
select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, h.SessionDate), 0)
```

This adds the number of months between `0` and `h.SessionDate` to `0`. `0` is converted to the `datetime` of `1900-01-01`.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MIM92003